# web service url for file uploading

Tags: web-services

does any one know any sample web service URL for file upload?some thing like this http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL 
except that the method should be a file upload method. thanx:)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to develop your own service you may want to consider Amazon S3. It is cloud storage, with scaling pricing depending on size of data stored, volume of traffic etc. It has an API - http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ - in both SOAP & REST formats.

Dropbox is built on the amazon service, so you'd be paying a dropbox premium for essentially the same service.

Answer (score 0):

Give http://cl.ly a try. Or http://dropbox.com